# Webgl Frustum view 

Tags: webgl

When I Render 5 boxes in webgl with 1 texture all of them, the app runs at 60 fps, nice. But when I render 70 boxes the performance dicrease to ~40fps but in the view volumes are still 5.

I have debugged the app and all 70 boxes are using per fragment shaders when there are no need because 65 of them are out of frustum. I thought that gl.viewport declaration clipped out of view polygons but not.

I would like to know if fustrum culling is the technique to avoid this? How can I activate fustrum culling? Is there any webgl command or I have to do it manually?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is this a copy-paste from some other Q&A?  With 'share' headings like LinkedIn, Twitter, and FB right in the first sentence of your question?  "0 down vote favorite share [fb] share [tw] share [in]". Sounds very non-genuine, especially with 'doubt' in the title.

Comment: Yes, its a copy paste from an unanswered old post of opengl es.

Comment: Please don't cross-post within the Stack Exchange network: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14587/webgl-rendering-performance-and-frustum-culling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed it: you have to do it manually.

But this technique is at the object level.. Individual triangles that are outside the viewport should be culled by the hardware automatically.

Is it possible that your draw loop has other inefficiencies that may be slowing things down as the number of boxes increases?  For example, are you binding the texture for each box?  Or querying the shader with getAttribLocation or getUniformLocation?  Or doing other WebGL queries (all of which will slow the pipeline dramatically)?

Comment: I fixed the code, I've implemented frustum clipping planes (sphere technique [link](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/)) before rendering and all is working better. I have ordered the textures not to bind each box, as you say. So now I am running at 60 fps again, thanks.

Comment: I recommend using Z pre-pass if having intensive fragment shaders as well.

Comment: @Joni,  I'm curious, if you remove frustum culling, do you still get 60fps?

Comment: @Joni - The scenarios where an early Z pass are beneficial are pretty limited (It only helps with very intensive fragment shaders, as you pointed out). As such it's normally not something I would recommend implementing unless you have evidence that you are fragment-limited. It doesn't sound like that is the case here.